# Como hacer todo list usando contextApi + localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, nextjs

lo unico que quiero hacer es un TODO list que se guarde en localstorage, lo cual ya logre, y por otro lado quiero tener esos datos en toda la app usando contextApi,lo raro es que esto ya lo hice usando redux y no tuve problemas.
Por algun motivo al hacer el dispatch hacia el reducer me sale el error de que `...state` no es iterable, pero yo veo perfectamente que el `payload` es un objeto y que el estado es un array de objetos. En pocas palabras no puedo hacer esto

```js
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'crear':
            return [action.payload,...state]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

les dejo el link de codesandbox para que vean en detalle

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-burnell-hrvs1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: ¿Se resolvio el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el problema es en la creación de la copia de `state`:

```
return [action.payload,...state];
```

Ahí se esta regresando un objeto `action.payload` y un array de objetos `state`,se esta **mutando** la estructura `state`.

Se debe regresar un array de objects, que sea consistente con la estructura `state` inicial y tratar el state como **inmutable**; además, hay que propagar el objeto `action.payload` para que se integre al resto de  elementos en el array `state`, que son otros objetos:

```
const reducer = (state = inititalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "crear":
      //regreso una copia array de objects
      //sin mutar la estructura state
      //propago los nuevos cambios action.payload a state
      return [{...action.payload, ...state}];

    case "setear":
      return {
        ...action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Espero que la respuesta sea de ayuda.